# Why is the location provided redundantly at two different places in the same object?

Tags: javascript, gis, bing-maps

I'm playing around with Bing Maps and running the following code, I noticed that the very exact same information on coordinates is provided at two places in the same object. Trusting that it's not a blunder from the designers, I wonder what the purpose of that apparent redundancy might be.

Are the values ever different?
Are they, perhaps, obtained in two different ways?

```
var geolocationProvider = new Microsoft.Maps
  .GeoLocationProvider(map).getCurrentPosition({
    successCallback: function(data) {
      var thisLatitude = data.position.coords.latitude;
      var alsoLatitude = data.center.latitude;
    } ...
});
```

The [API for getCurrentPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125839.aspx) states that I get two entities:
1. [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427612.aspx) containing info on latitude, longitude and altitude
2. [Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125832.aspx), the [coordinates of which](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125835.aspx) contain info on latitude, longitude and altitude

Can't see why the duck (typo intended) this redundancy...

Comment: According to [the `PositionOptions` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125839.aspx), `position` represents [*"...the position of **a user** on a map..."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125832.aspx); `center` represents [*"...the altitude and coordinate values of a **location** on the map..."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427612.aspx) *(my emphasis)*. Perhaps your greater knowledge of Bing maps will tell you whether that's useful information; I've never used them, that was a glance at the documentation.

Comment: Oh, I know as much about Bing Maps as ostriches about aviation. But I'm taking your comment as a suggestion to extend my question with convenient links to the API (which I lazily omitted). Sadly, in my head, "*location*" and "*position*" are synonymous so I don't see the technical difference.   :(

Comment: @ Konrad: It's just it seems to be suggesting some distinction between "a location" and the *user's* location, if that makes any sense. Good luck with it!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Possibly... Please feel free to put your comment as a reply so I can upvote it (and perhaps mark as an answer, should no one else come with anything heavier). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125839.aspx The center is self explanatory. The position contains all the raw data from the GPS/location API.

Comment: I know where it's documented because I posted the URL in my question, which seems to be copied over in your reply. As for the difference between *center* and *coords*, if it'd be self-explanatory, I wouldn't ask. Since the API doesn't explain that, please feel free to provide an example where they differ.

Comment: Most people just want the center coordinate when using this API, however others want all the information from the Geolocation API  (W3C API) which is in the position property. The full response from the Geolocation API contains the coordinates as well.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the information in *center* and *coords* will always present the same *longitude* and *altitude*, then? It seems so unexpected to store the same data twice... One'd expect a deeper and more intricate design though behind such a choice.